# Returning the same found Substring in a String

Tags: java

Here I have this code below. the idea is having a phrase like `"R#GUPW*UIOPW#WERTY*RT#LLOPPPPER*CVW"` to return a pattern like

`"#GUPW*"`
`"#WERTY*"`
`"#LLOPPPPER*"`

that is returning all the Substrings from the phrase which begin with # and ends with *. so in this phrase there is 3 of them.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Pattern {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        String phrase = "R#GUPW*UIOPW#WERTY*RT#LLOPPPPER*CVW";
        String found ="";

        for (int y = 0; y<phrase.length(); y++)
        {
        found = found + phrase.substring(phrase.indexOf("#"), phrase.indexOf("*"));
        }
        System.out.println(found);
    }

}
```

but my code returns
`"#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW#GUPW"`

how can I return these substrings which begin with # and ends with  * from my phrase.

`"#GUPW*"`
`"#WERTY*"`
`"#LLOPPPPER*"`

Comment: `indexOf` when not called with more parameters always searchs from the start of the string. So it will always find "#GUPW"

Comment: This is not clear but. You are iterating on every character but you used indexOf method from the beginning each time. If you iterate like this, check the current character, if it is `#` or not. Or simply search for every `#` and do your thing. PS : You example is not correct since you are missing the `*`, or I didn't understand

Comment: Ask yourself, why do you have y variable at all in loop? You are not using it anywhere? Do you expect to have phrase.length() unique printouts from your program? Further hints: - use while loop, store indices found to variables so you can use them in more then just substring call and read documentation about 2-parameter indexOf methods.

Comment: I gave you working code below. Please ask if you need some further explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be to define a `Pattern` and then use it in a `Matcher`.

```
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#[^*]+\\*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourString);
while (m.find()) {
   allMatches.add(m.group());
 }
```

Then, all matches will appear in the `List`.

Demo:

```
String s = "R#GUPW*UIOPW#WERTY*RT#LLOPPPPER*CVW";
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#[^*]+\\*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    allMatches.add(m.group());
}

for (String str : allMatches) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
>>#GUPW*
>>#WERTY*
>>#LLOPPPPER*
```

Comment: I was awaiting a `Pattern` to ask what would append in case of `#foo*bar*boo`. In doubt, I used a more _manual_ solution

Comment: @AxelH good point. The above solution would pic a foo. I believe this is what the OP wants.

Comment: Since this was not asked, I didn't took that as a requirement at all. I wasn't sure of what this would output. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I can't understand why so many people are trying to extract certain indexes, when regex is a tool which is designed for these purposes :p

Comment: I know... but I like the challenges when I am bored ;)

Comment: Thanks for the great answers guys.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply search for every `*` and then from this position find the previous `#` if any. This would look like this :

```
String input = "R#test*foo#bar#far#bor*for#";

int index = -1, begin;
while((index = input.indexOf("*", index+1)) > -1){
     if((begin = input.lastIndexOf("#", index)) > -1){ //If there is a character
          // Substract it from the current String
          System.out.println(input.substring(begin, index + 1));
      }
}
```

Basicly, search for the next `*` beginning from `index + 1`(+ 1 to prevent an infinite loop) with

```
input.indexOf("*", index+1))
```

From there, simply use `String.lastIndexOf` to search from this position the previous `#`. In case of two `*` in a Substring, this solution will print both.

This output :

```
#test
#bor
```

Comment: Your output is wrong...And according to your doubt about multiple stars. Look, the OP has three stars and expects 3 outputs instead of 6.

Comment: @xenteros My output is missing the `*` indeed. But this output the exact same string with OP example.... So yes, this might be wrong in the case of `#foo*bar*far` should only output one String but this is easy to fix (if needed)

Answer (score 0):

There is already a method in String utils within Apache Commons Libraries that does that for you. The method is StringUtils.[substringsBetween](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringsBetween-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

> public static String[] substringsBetween(String str,
>                                            String open,
>                                            String close) Searches a String for substrings delimited by a start and end tag, returning all
>   matching substrings in an array.
>
> A null input String returns null. A null open/close returns null (no
>   match). An empty ("") open/close returns null (no match).

```
StringUtils.substringsBetween("[a][b][c]", "[", "]") = ["a","b","c"] 
StringUtils.substringsBetween(null, *, *)            = null 
StringUtils.substringsBetween(*, null, *)            = null 
StringUtils.substringsBetween(*, *, null)            = null 
StringUtils.substringsBetween("", "[", "]")          = []
```

> Parameters:
>
> - str - the String containing the substrings, null returns null, empty returns empty
> - open - the String identifying the start of the substring, empty returns null close - the String identifying the
> - end - of the substring, empty returns null Returns: a String Array of substrings, or null if no match

This method doesn't include the separators in the output so if you really need it I guess you'll need to fix the behaviour with few lines of code.

Comment: This is using Apache API. you should specify it ;) Not everybody used it (I never had the need)

Comment: @AxelH ApacheCommons as well as Guava is usually added to a project at the  moment of creating a POM :)

Comment: I could agree, never add the needs so I can't judge ;) but this need to be in his answer. Yes this is in the link but this is not necessary clear for newbies. (PS, not the downvoter, I found this solution useful but uncomplete)

Comment: Guys you're really strict :-D I edited the answer as advised, however I don't really understand the downvote as my solution solves the issue and the original question doesn't require explicitly the use of Standard Libraries.

Comment: @AR1, I agree, I was a bit picky here but I remember when I begin to dev, I was lost with all those methods that I couldn't found because this was not from the JDK. But no idea why this was downvote, this is a correct answer and nicely written (extract the important part of the link).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code inside the loop to

```
int stIndex = phrase.indexOf("#");
int endIndex = phrase.indexOf("*");
found = found + "\n" + phrase.substring(stIndex, endIndex);
phrase = phrase.substring(endIndex + 1);
```

What I did is after finding the first match I am removing the matched string from the input.

Answer (score -2):

```
   String phrase = "R#GUPW*UIOPW#WERTY*RT#LLOPPPPER*CVW";
   String[] ph = phrase.substring(phrase.indexOf("#"), phrase.lastIndexOf("*")+1) //get everything between the first "#" and last "*"                           
                       .replaceAll("\\*.*?#", "*#") // remove all chars between * and #
                       .split("(?<=\\*)"); //split at * and keep the delimiter
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ph));
```